# Recursively count number of triangles in Sierpinski triangle

Tags: c++, recursion

I have this function that returns the number of triangles in a Sierpinski triangle based on the order.
I need to calculate it by summing the amounts from the recursive calls.
I'm not able to use static variables, modify the function parameters, or use global variables.
I tried using int count but I know that won't necessarily work because it'll be reset during the call.

```
int drawSierpinskiTriangle(GWindow& window, GPoint one, GPoint two, GPoint three, int order) {

    if (order == 0) fillBlackTriangle(window, one, two, three); // order 0 triangle

    // one is left point, two is right point, three is top point
    else {
        int count = 0;
        GPoint bottom = { (one.x + two.x)/ 2, (one.y + two.y)/ 2 }; // bottom side of triangle
        GPoint right = { (two.x + three.x)/ 2, (two.y + three.y)/ 2 }; // right  side of triangle
        GPoint left = { (one.x + three.x)/ 2, (one.y + three.y)/ 2 }; // left  side of triangle

        drawSierpinskiTriangle(window, one, left, bottom, order - 1);
        drawSierpinskiTriangle(window, two, right, bottom, order - 1);
        drawSierpinskiTriangle(window, three, left, right, order - 1);

        count++;

        return count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn’t reset if you pass it as a variable. That’s how recursion works. Just make sure to pass it as a reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation of `drawSierpinskiTriangle` will only return **0 or 1**:
**0** if `order == 0`,
or:
**1** otherwise (because `count` is initialized to 0 and you use `count++` **once** after **all** the recursive calls).

Instead of using `count++`, you should **accumulate the result** from the recursive calls:

```
count += drawSierpinskiTriangle(window, one, left, bottom, order - 1);
count += drawSierpinskiTriangle(window, two, right, bottom, order - 1);
count += drawSierpinskiTriangle(window, three, left, right, order - 1);
```

In addition you should **return 1 when the recursion reaches the end** (otherwise you will only accumulate zeroes):

```
if (order == 0)
{
    fillBlackTriangle(window, one, two, three); // order 0 triangle
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why return 1 is necessary? I'm not sure why omitting it will only accumulate zeroes. What happens to count if I don't return 1?

Comment: As explained in my answer `count` is only updated by adding the return value of the recuresive calls. If you'll return 0 at the end of the recuresion, `count += ...` will only add 0 to count. I suggest you walk through it with a debugger (or add prints for the return value of each call to `drawSierpinskiTriangle`) and you'll see that you will only ever get 0. Another way to look at it: you function is supposed to count triangles. At the end of the recursion where you actually draw 1 triangle you should return 1 (for the 1 you just drew).